# Why left and right circular polarized light add to be linear polarized light in $x$ direction but not in $y$ direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, polarization

Quote

> One of the applications of the Jones notation is calculating the result of adding two or more waves of given polarizations. The result is obtained simply by adding the Jones vectors. As an example, suppose we want to know the result of adding two waves of equal amplitude, one being right circularly polarized, the other left circularly polarized. The calculation by means of the Jones vectors proceeds as follows:
>   \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -i \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ i \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
>   The last expression shows that the resultant wave is linearly polarized in the x direction and its amplitude is twice that of either of the circular components.

However, this really didn't make any sense, because one can just rotate x-y plane about z axis in any degree, as the light does not care much if $x$ was $y$ or $y$ was $x$.

Why left and right circular polarized light add to be linear polarized light in $x$ direction but not in $y$ direction? or just any linear direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two circularly polarized waves *of the same amplitude* always add up to be a linearly polarized wave in some direction.  The particular direction depends on the phases of the two waves.  Suppose for example that at a location Z and moment *t* the E field vector of one of the waves is pointing at 45 degrees to the left of vertical, and at the same location and moment the other wave is also pointing in the same direction, 45 degrees to the left.  In that case, the two beams will add together to form a linearly polarized wave whose polarization is oriented 45 degrees to the left.  If the phase of the second beam is delayed by $n$ degrees, the polarization of the beam will simply rotate by $n$ degrees.  The direction of rotation will of course depend on whether the first beam's polarization is right circular (A) or left circular (b). In case (A) the rotation will be toward the right.